# iOS UIView 3D border

Tags: ios, uiview, opengl-es-2.0

I have been working on coin like UIView, which has 3d rotation.

I was able to implement rotate effect with CATransform3dRotate, based on the gesture. Now I need to implement shadow like effect, when image rotates.

Please refer to the image attached herewith.

Any suggestions? recommendations? or sample code would be great

[Sample Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/848Ea.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps you want to use OpenGL or SpriteKit, or some graphics package that has support for lighting and true 3D rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/scenekit/). I've put together a quick demo, which you can download [here](https://github.com/judson-douglas/3d-spinning-coin.git), of a 3D coin object which rotates horizontally left or right by a swipe gesture, with a realistic light source and shadowing. The relevant code follows:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!

    let rotate90AboutZ = SCNAction.rotateByX(0.0, y: 0.0, z: CGFloat(M_PI_2), duration: 0.0)

    var currentAngle: Float = 0.0
    var coinNode = SCNNode()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sceneView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        coinSceneSetup()
    }

    func coinSceneSetup() {

        let coinScene = SCNScene()
        //coin is rendered as a cylinder with a very small height
        let coinGeometry = SCNCylinder(radius: 50, height: 2)
        coinNode = SCNNode(geometry: coinGeometry)
        coinNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 25.0, 25.0)
        coinScene.rootNode.addChildNode(coinNode)
        //rotate coin 90 degrees about the z axis so that it stands upright
        coinNode.runAction(rotate90AboutZ)

        let shinyCoinMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        shinyCoinMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        shinyCoinMaterial.specular.contents = UIColor.whiteColor()
        shinyCoinMaterial.shininess = 1.0
        coinGeometry.firstMaterial = shinyCoinMaterial
        sceneView.scene = coinScene
        let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panGesture:")
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
    }

    //allows for coin to spin with a right or left finger swipe, while still keeping it rotated 90 degrees about z axis
    func panGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = sender.translationInView(sender.view!)
        var newAngle = (Float)(translation.x)*(Float)(M_PI)/180.0
        newAngle += currentAngle
        coinNode.runAction(SCNAction.rotateToX(CGFloat(newAngle), y: 0.0, z: CGFloat(M_PI_2), duration: 0.0))
        if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
            currentAngle = newAngle
        }
    }      
}
```

Several excellent introductory tutorials are available, for example [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83748/beginning-scene-kit-tutorial), [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-scenekit-fundamentals--cms-23847), and [here](http://ronnqvi.st/3d-with-scenekit/). weheartswift.com put out a three part tutorial in Swift that I personally find especially useful. Here are parts [1](https://www.weheartswift.com/introduction-scenekit-part-1/), [2](https://www.weheartswift.com/introduction-scenekit-part-2/) and [3](https://www.weheartswift.com/introduction-scenekit-part-3/).

Jeff Lamarche's [introduction](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.se/2012/08/an-introduction-to-scenekit.html) to SceneKit on OS X, along with his accompanying [source code](https://github.com/jlamarche/SceneKitFun) is a valuable resource as well.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I really appreciate your efforts.